# How to create a view of all elements in many collections in Java?

Tags: java, collections

I have this boilderplace code

```
for(Person p: school.getStudents())
    p.setName(null);

for(Person p: school.getTeachers())
    p.setName(null);

for(Person p: school.getStrangers())
    p.setName(null);
```

I it possible to "combine" all those collections in a view (ie. avoid copying / allocating memory like via `addAll()`) and iterate over the view?

e.g.

```
for(Person p: allOf(school.getStudents(), school.getTeachers(), school.getStrangers())
    p.setName(null);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Guava's [`Iterables.concat()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat%28java.lang.Iterable...%29) method. It creates a view over multiple iterables passed to it, and then you can iterate over the resulting `Iterable`.

Comment: sounds nice; anything in JDK?

Comment: @user3733425 Nope. Not before Java 8 where you've Streams.

Comment: @user3733425 Anyways, you would love to include Guava library in any of your projects. It provides hell lot of useful utilities, and a great API. Certainly a major plus for any Java project.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a method, which does this for you.

something like:

```
private List<Person> allOf(List<Person>... collections) {
    List<Person> result = new ArrayList<Person>();
    for (List<Person> element : collections) {
        result.addAll(element);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: addAll is exactly what I want to avoid :)

Comment: Sure, then the next better approach would be, you just make a method, which gets a List of Persons, and operates on this list. This way, you have to call the method multiple times, but you avoid writing the handling code multiple times -> privavte void setNamesToNull(List<Person> persons){ for (Person p : persons){ p.setName(null);}}